# delta indexes in sphinx on a child node- thinkingsphinx

Tags: sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I have a model restaurant and offers  ( has_many                :offers) , The sphinx index it self is on the restaurant level .  I want to have a delta index which is based on new offers for restaurants or update for current one.
What's the best way to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that this question could be useful for your problem:

[Using Delta Indexes for associations in Thinking Sphinx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902804/using-delta-indexes-for-associations-in-thinking-sphinx)