# What is the equivalent of 'index_delta' in Thinking Sphinx v3?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job, thinking-sphinx

This question is related to this one: [Using Delta Indexes for associations in Thinking Sphinx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902804/using-delta-indexes-for-associations-in-thinking-sphinx#)

I have exactly the same dilemma right now. I tried the solution posted by Pat and Claudio but no luck since I'm using Thinking Sphinx version 3.0.6.

I'm using ts delayed delta gem as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is covered here: https://github.com/pat/thinking-sphinx/issues/780 - but the short answer is:

```
ThinkingSphinx::Deltas::IndexJob.new('product_delta').perform
```

If you want to queue it up in Delayed Job, though, then the following is what you're after:

```
Delayed::Job.enqueue(
  ThinkingSphinx::Deltas::DelayedDelta::DeltaJob.new('product_delta')
)
```